# Why is my view stretching over list view boundaries?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

The problem consists of, in this case, two views going out of planed boundaries of a list view. First of all the whole list view should be under the text view:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tptp"
```

Second, right side of the view stretches out of screen even though its width is set to match_parent.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

My Activity:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListOfChatsActivity">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/slika1" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="126dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="@color/logoBlue"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/picture"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/picture"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/picture" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:textColor="@color/logoBlue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/phone"
        android:textColor="@color/logoBlue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/email"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/email"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tptp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:background="@color/logoBlue"
        android:text="@string/contacts"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="269dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tptp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the View:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/customborder">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chatName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/logoBlue"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/last_seen"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chatName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="@string/date"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView6" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Picture of the error:

[image]

Most likely its a simple mistake since i never got an similar error, but i still can't seem to find it.

Comment: Why is listView's width static and equal to 410 dp? The width and height of the listview should be 0dp if you want it to respect the constraints you put, probably the screens width is less than 410 dp and that's why the list item is wider.

Comment: Uncomfortable part is that i was checking the code for two hours and managed to miss that. Tnx for the effort anyway.